# Pandas. Use groupby() with dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
              USDBRL
date                
1994-01-03  331.2200
1994-01-04  336.4900
1994-01-05  341.8300
1994-01-06  347.2350
1994-01-07  352.7300
             ...
2020-10-05    5.6299
2020-10-06    5.5205
2020-10-07    5.6018
2020-10-08    5.6200
2020-10-09    5.5393
```

`date` is a `datetime index`. I would like to filter the `df` just with the highest day of each month. First I created a `months` list:

`months = df.index.to_period('M')`

Next, I'm trying to use the following code in my `datetime index` to select only the last month's day:

`df = df.groupby(months).idxmax()`

but this is not giving me what I want. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your data is sorted in descending order by date.

```
df.groupby(df.index.month).tail(1)
```